# How to go to a new page by changing URL while continuing to run code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-history, history.js

I have a chrome extension that selects all the items on a page and clicks through them one-by-one. It then clicks on a few other buttons on the individual item pages.

```
allItems = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++ ) {
    let currentItem = allItems[i];
    currentItem.click();

    // PAUSE, then on the next page click on edit button
    editButton.click();

    // PAUSE, then on the next page click on save button
    saveButton.click();

    // PAUSE, then go back to the home page and click on next item
    homePageButton.click();
}
```

This all works fine (I use an async function to leave a pause between page loads).

But now I want to go each item page by changing the URL, rather than by clicking on each item with .click().

My problem is that if I use something like window.open, the page reloads and the code stops executing.

How can I navigate to a new page by changing the URL and still allow my code to execute like happens when I click the Items using .click()?

Comment: `window.open` opens a new window so it's unclear why the current page reloads as they should be unrelated. Maybe there's a problem in your code, show it.

Comment: When the new page opens it is a new URL meaning a new content page must load. Do you have permission for the new URL? Once you click on open your currently executing content page does not follow on in the new page.

Comment: Thanks @darbid, what you described is exactly my problem.

Is there any way to get the currently executing content page to follow onto the new page?

Comment: From my experience no. New tab new content page. But if there is a way wOxxOm will know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data or results from multiple tabs background script might be the place.
Let the content script do the clicks, data collection etc and send the data back to background scripts where data will be stored.